# PHP Pow Function a reverse required

Tags: php

I have something with pow I need to return a whole inter for different results (reversed basically)

For Example (rounded to 4 decimals):

```
<?php
$var = 10 * pow(1.01,0); // = 10
$var = 10 * pow(1.01,1); // = 10.1
$var = 10 * pow(1.01,2); // = 10.201
$var = 10 * pow(1.01,3); // = 10.303
```

etc

How could I return the whole number for `10.1150 = 1` since it is above `10 * pow(1.01,1);` and below `10 * pow(1.01,2);`

The `1.01` can also be a number of variables, (percentage scaled point and figure charting), why I need the Whole number only of the percentage differences (1 box = 1 percentage change from the box above or below)

Thanks much all, I've battled with this issue in many different ways including x all price data points for 250 percentage changed into an array, that is fast, except to build the array becomes the slow issue.  `if else` is the current solution but for **2500 price points on 250 charts = 2 seconds** just to find a plot point, considering I'm doing 10's of millions of charts daily, 2 seconds = a lot of time accumulated.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `log`? It's the reverse of the `pow` function.

```
$orig = floor(log($var/10,1.01));
```

Comment: I'll try that, see what it produces, thanks, if that works, will be a heap of time cut out of millions of charts processed.

$orig = floor(log($var/10,1.01)); think this is gonna == the result I'm looking for, can't round up, have to take base, but thanks so much, :)

Comment: Sweet ! , I owe you a beer there Licson :)